# Clock minute-hand disappears when attempting to rotate it

Tags: calayer, cgaffinetransform, swift3

**Modus Operandi:** 
1) Use an UIImageView of a base Clock Image. 
2) Add MinuteHand & HourHand sublayers (containing their respective images) to the UIImageView layer.

**Problem:** both sublayers *disappear* when attempting to perform a rotation transformation.

**Note:** 
 1) I've removed the 'hour' code & ancillary radian calculations to simplify code. 
2) The 'center' is the center of the clock.  I had adjusted the coordinates to actually pin the hands to the clock's center. 
3) The ViewDidLayoutSubviews() *appear to be okay*.  I got the clock + hands.

```
class ClockViewController:UIViewController {

    private let minuteLayer = CALayer()

    @IBOutlet weak var clockBaseImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var datePicker: UIDatePicker!

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

        guard var minuteSize = UIImage(named: "MinuteHand")?.size,
              var hourSize = UIImage(named: "HourHand")?.size
        else {
            return
        }

        var contentLayer:CALayer {
            return self.view.layer
        }

        var center = clockBaseImageView.center

        // Minute Hand:
        minuteLayer.setValue("*** Minute Hand ***", forKey: "id")
        minuteSize = CGSize(width: minuteSize.width/3, height: minuteSize.height/3)
        minuteLayer.contents = UIImage(named: "MinuteHand")?.cgImage

        center = CGPoint(x: 107.0, y: 40.0)
        var handFrame = CGRect(origin: center, size: minuteSize)
        minuteLayer.frame = handFrame
        minuteLayer.contentsScale = clockBaseImageView.layer.contentsScale
        minuteLayer.anchorPoint = center

        clockBaseImageView.layer.addSublayer(minuteLayer)

    }
```

**Here's my problem:** Attempting to rotate the minute hand via 0.01 radians:

```
func set(_ time:Date) {
        minuteLayer.setAffineTransform(CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .01))   // random value for test.
}
```

Before rotation attempt:

[image]

After attempting to rotate minute hand: 
[image]

The hand shifted laterally to the right vs rotate. 
Why?  Perhaps due to the pivot point?

Comment: 1 radian is a non-trivial test rotation. (It's around a sixth of a circle.) Try something smaller, then try something smaller and negative, and you'll have a better chance of seeing what's wrong.

Comment: I made the change per request: to 0.01 radians.   I notice the minute hand shifted (slide over) to the right.   But no rotation.  Perhaps I got the pivot/anchor wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will solve your problem, Take a look and let me know.

```
     import GLKit // Importing GLKit Framework

     func set(_ time:Date) {
       minuteLayer.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(GLKMathDegreesToRadians(0.01)))
     }
```

Comment: The minuteLayer.transform expects a 'CATransform3D' vs 'CGAffineTransform' struct.  So this wouldn't compile.  Perhaps I should manually build a CGAffineTransform struct and apply it.

Comment: I found another route: work with subviews vs sublayers.   This appears to be simpler with predictable result.

Comment: @FrederickC.Lee Okay.

Answer (score 0):

Note: this solution doesn't solve the issue about *rotating a **CALayer***. 
 Instead, it bypasses the issue by replacing the layer with a **subview** and rotating the **subview** via:

```
 func set(_ time:Date) {
        minuteView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 45 * CGFloat(M_PI)/180.0)
 }
```

Here's the result: 
[image]

Still, it would be nice to know how to rotate a CALayer.